# Split text inside align*

Tags: beamer, align

I have a function definition like this:[image]

inside a `beamer` presentation. The text inside the set definition to which the function maps to is very long and does not fit on the slide.

I want to split it in multiple lines, while keeping the alignment of the function definition.

Code:

```
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{F} \colon \{ \mathbf{AFDs} \quad \text{sin estados inalcanzables} \} \quad &\longrightarrow \quad \{ \text{really long text that does not fit on the slide} \} \\
    M \quad &\longmapsto \quad \equiv_{M}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal **working** example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Even if your question is clear, well written and formatted, and you gave us the critical part of your code; easily reproducing the problem will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Thank you !

Comment: I would use a \parbox, although you would need to guess the width.

Comment: if the text is really text not mathematics just change `\text{..}` to `\parbox{4cm}{...}` or whatever width you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) and [@John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo) commented, if the text does not contain math, a [`\parbox`](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/$5cparbox.html) solves the problem nicely.

```
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{F} \colon \{ \mathbf{AFDs} \quad \text{sin estados inalcanzables} \} \quad &\longrightarrow \quad \parbox{80pt}{\{relaciones Myhill-Nerode\}} \\
    M \quad &\longmapsto \quad \equiv_{M}
\end{align*}
```

[image]